# jQuery slideUp/Down fadeIn/Out Asymmetry

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to alternate display between two containers on a page using fadeOut/fadeIn & slideUp/slideDown. I would like the transition from the first container to the second to look the same as the transition from the second to the first; they fade in/out respectively, the current container slides up and away, and the other slides up from below it, all simultaneously. The first button triggers the animation described, but when I use the second button to transition to the first element the first element suddenly pops into existence while fading in jerking the page down, the second fades out, but no slide occurs. Thanks for your help, and let me know if I can clarify for you!

```
var main = function () {

$('.button-1').click(function () {
    $('.container-1').fadeOut({ duration: 1400, queue: false }).slideUp(1400);
    $('.container-2').fadeIn({ duration: 1400, queue: false }).slideDown(1400);
});


$('.button-2').click(function () {
    $('.container-2').stop(true, true).fadeOut({ duration: 1400, queue: true }).slideUp(1400);
    $('.container-1').fadeIn({ duration: 1400, queue: false }).slideDown(1400);

});
$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: Can include `html` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you actually only need 1 button to do this if you animate the height and opacity with toggle. ive added it twice since your use case was for 2 buttons
[js fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/zq7drwkj/7/)

js

```
var main = function () {

    $('.button-1').click(function () {

        $('.container-1')
            .stop(true, true)
            .animate({
            height: "toggle",
            opacity: "toggle"
        }, 1400);
        $('.container-2')
            .stop(true, true)
            .animate({
            height: "toggle",
            opacity: "toggle"
        }, 1400);
    });

    $('.button-2').click(function () {
        $('.container-2')
            .stop(true, true)
            .animate({
            height: "toggle",
            opacity: "toggle"
        }, 1400);
        $('.container-1')
            .stop(true, true)
            .animate({
            height: "toggle",
            opacity: "toggle"
        }, 1400);
    });
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

html

```
<div class=container-1>container1</div>
<div class=container-2>container2</div>
<input type=button class=button-1 value=button1>
<input type=button class=button-2 value=button2>
```

css

```
.button-1 {
    color: red;
}
.button-2 {
    color: blue;
}
.container-1, .container-2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.container-1 {
    background-color: green;
}
.container-2 {
    display: none;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: I needed the two buttons because one is in each container, but this works beautifully! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want. But here is one way to switch between two containers with slide and fade at the same time:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" class="redclick" value="Red"></input>
<input type="button" class="blueclick" value="Blue"></input>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.red, .blue{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position: absolute;
}

.red{ background:red; }
.blue{ background:blue; }
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {
     $('.red').hide();
     $('.blue').show();

     $(".blueclick").click(function() {
         if($('.red').css('opacity') == '1'){
              $('.red').fadeOut({ duration: 1400, queue: false }).slideUp(1400);
              $('.blue').slideDown({ duration: 1400, queue: false }).fadeIn(1400);
         }
     });
     $(".redclick").click(function() {
         if($('.blue').css('opacity') == '1'){
              $('.blue').fadeOut({ duration: 1400, queue: false }).slideUp(1400);
              $('.red').slideDown({ duration: 1400, queue: false }).fadeIn(1400);
         }
     });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qv2fhwrk/1/)**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help! But the fiddle isn't working for me chrome/firefox/ie :(